# Still working in Android Login

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, authentication

me again, in my previous post, i was told to use AsyncTask in codes, to avoid mainexceptionthread, and now i'm encountering this errors:

**

```
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4609)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10193)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateRegion(TextView.java:4375)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4318)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7172)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8759)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:979)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:688)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3535)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at com.example.projectthesis.Main$phpconnect.doInBackground(Main.java:98)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at com.example.projectthesis.Main$phpconnect.doInBackground(Main.java:1)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-26 09:39:06.220: E/AndroidRuntime(17218):    ... 5 more
```

**

i think it is because of the Exception e part, which has inputEmail.setText(e.toString());
but when i am changing it to just e.printstacktrace, it results nothing. Can you help me here guys these are my codes:

android:

**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        // button click event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                validation();
            }
        }); 
    }

    public void validation()
    {
        if(inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("") || inputPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Fill Empty Fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
        else
        {
             new phpconnect().execute();
        }
        }


    class phpconnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eadd", inputEmail.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", inputPassword.getText().toString()));
                //Passing Parameter to the php web service for authentication
                //String valid = "1";
                String response = null;
                try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/TheCalling/log_in.php", postParameters);  //Enter Your remote PHP,ASP, Servlet file link
                String res=response.toString();
                //res = res.trim();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                //error.setText(res);
                if(res.equals("1"))
                {
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Correct Username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Main.this,MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                    else
                        if(res.equals("0"))
                    {
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    inputEmail.setText(e.toString());
                }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        } 

    }


}
```

**

This again my PHP codes:

**

```
<?php
include("db_config.php");
$eadd=addslashes($_POST['eadd']);
$password=addslashes($_POST['password']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE eadd='$eadd' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1)
    {
    echo "1";
    //(If result found send 1 to android)
    }
else
    {
    echo "0";
    //(If result not found send o to android)
    }
?>
```

**

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views`

Comment: hmm, can you explain in to me, i don't understand. sorry

Comment: Why are you updating your view in doInBackground? It is a background thread, all the operations on main thread should be done in postExecute method of AsyncTask

Comment: Since this is your fourth question regarding the login thing you're writing I'd suggest that you slow down and read up on Android programming.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because of:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    inputEmail.setText(e.toString());
}
```

Over here you try to alter the app's UI by altering the contents of an EditText from the background thread of the AsyncTask. Since I doubt you actually want to show an error to the user in the email input field and are doing this just for debugging purposes, try using `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `inputEmail.setText(e.toString());`

Additionally, you'll want to wrap your `Toast.show()` calls in a `runOnUiThread()` runnable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't show the toast messages in `doInBackground` just move it to `onPostExecute`. and yes also this

```
catch (Exception e) {
                    inputEmail.setText(e.toString());
                }
```